# date_default_timezone_get is sometimes slow to load

Tags: php

I am not sure why we added in the below to set the timezone but maybe 1 out of every 100 calls to date_default_timezone_get can take 5+ milliseconds to load. Does anyone have any information on why this would sometimes run slow? Servers are running on Google Cloud CentOS Linux 7 with PHP Version 5.6.40 (Yes I know it needs updated)

```
// LOAD TIME: 1.692ms
if (!date_default_timezone_get('date.timezone'))    {
    // NEVERHIT
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    // LOAD TIME: 6.794ms
}
```

Comment: I do not know why but I can almost bet that with PHP 7.4 and above you will achieve some significant increase in speeds. I do not know much about cloud but on physical computers, reducing RAM size also reduces performance of PHP and the inverse is true. I do not think it has anything to do with CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if (!date_default_timezone_get('date.timezone'))    {
```

generates the warning

> Warning: date_default_timezone_get() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1
> given in ..

That takes a lot of time. An if condition that is always true also makes no sense.
The instruction

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
```

only takes a fraction of the time from instruction that generats warnings. The date_default_timezone_set() command should always be executed if there are uncertainties about the time zone of the environment.